# Issue with Laravel 4.2 Session::put method

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have a method that I use to store files in session and upload in directory, after that I get data from session and save in database.

I have issue with this method. Sometimes it works correct but there are cases when not all items have been saved in session.

I'm using Laravel `Session::put()` method to save separate items into session array. Every time user changes some input type file on the form, this method is invoked.

For example, I have 3 input type files. Sometimes when I try to upload files, it saves ins ession `front_passport` field and `address_document` field but it doesn't save `back_passport` field.

Is there some case with Laravel session and using it in some way?

My code is the following:

```js
$(".app-file").on('change', function(){
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append($(this).attr('name'), this.files[0]);
        formData.append('name', $(this).attr('name'));
        $.ajax({
            url: store_files,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.errors) {
                     $.each(response.errors, function (k, v) {
                        $('[name=' + k + ']').parent().find('.file-name').html('');
                        $('<label class="error file_error">' + v + '</label>').insertAfter($('[name=' + k + ']').next().next());
                    });
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                $('.ajax-error').remove();
                $('<span class="error col-md-6 ajax-error">There is some error! Please try again later!</span>').insertAfter($('.upload-section h3'));
            }
        });

    });
```

```html
 public function storeFiles() {
       $name = Input::get('name'); //input name
        $input = Input::all();
        $input_file = Input::file($name);
        $current_time = time();
        $allowed =  array('jpeg','jpg','gif','png','pdf');
       
         $file_name = $current_time . '_' . $input_file->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = File::extension($file_name);

            if (!in_array($extension, $allowed)) {
                return Response::json(array(
                    'success' => false,
                    'errors' => [$name => 'Please provide an image with one of the following extensions : jpg, gif, png or pdf']
                ));
            }

            $current_session = Session::get($name); //delete existing image from directory
            $item_path = APPLICATIONS_DIR.'/'.$current_session;
            if (file_exists($item_path) && !empty($current_session)) {
                $removed_file = unlink($item_path);
            }

            if ($input_file) {
                $input_file->move(APPLICATIONS_DIR, $file_name);
            }
            Session::put($name, $file_name);


         return Response::json(array(
            'files' => ['name' => $name,'session' => Session::all()]
        ));
        

}
```

My html is:

```html
 <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="front_passport" class="col-md-2 label-file">{{translate("Front ID/Passport")}}<span class="required-label">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 file-wrapper">
                                {{ Form::file('front_passport',  ["class"=>"app-file"]) }}
                                <label for="front_passport" class="file-upload"><span>{{translate("Upload a File")}}</span></label>
                                <div class="file-name" data-input="front_passport"></div>
                                <label for="front_passport" generated="true"  class="<?php echo $errors->has('front_passport') ? 'error' : '';?>">{{ $errors->first('front_passport') }}</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="back_passport" class="col-md-2 label-file">{{translate("Back ID/Passport")}}<span class="required-label">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 file-wrapper">
                                {{ Form::file('back_passport',  ["class"=>"app-file"]) }}
                                <label for="back_passport" class="file-upload"><span>{{translate("Upload a File")}}</span></label>
                                <div class="file-name" data-input="back_passport"></div>
                                <label for="back_passport" generated="true"  class="<?php echo $errors->has('back_passport') ? 'error' : '';?>">{{ $errors->first('back_passport') }}</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="address_document" class="col-md-2 label-file">{{translate("Proof of Address")}}<span class="required-label">*</span></label>
                            <div class="col-md-8 file-wrapper">
                                {{ Form::file('address_document',  ["class"=>"app-file"]) }}
                                <label for="address_document" class="file-upload"><span>{{translate("Upload a File")}}</span></label>
                                <div class="file-name" data-input="address_document"></div>
                                <label for="address_document" generated="true"  class="<?php echo $errors->has('address_document') ? 'error' : '';?>">{{ $errors->first('address_document') }}</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The laravel session has a lifetime, you can configure it from app/session.php. But that is no the case here - when you delete a file if it is already exist in the directory.
I don't think you need a session inorder to find the existing file, simply use php file_exists function

```
public function storeFiles() {
    $name = Input::get('name'); //input name
    $input = Input::all();
    $input_file = Input::file($name);
    $current_time = time();
    $allowed = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'pdf');

    $file_name = $current_time . '_' . $input_file->getClientOriginalName();
    $extension = File::extension($file_name);

    if (!in_array($extension, $allowed)) {
        return Response::json(array(
                    'success' => false,
                    'errors' => [$name => 'Please provide an image with one of the following extensions : jpg, gif, png or pdf']
        ));
    }


    //delete existing image from directory
    $item_path = APPLICATIONS_DIR . '/' . $file_name;
    if (file_exists($item_path)) {
        $removed_file = unlink($item_path);
    }

    if ($input_file) {
        $input_file->move(APPLICATIONS_DIR, $file_name);
    }

    return Response::json(array(
                'files' => ['name' => $name, 'session' => [$name => $file_name]]
    ));
}
```